# Angular 5 Routing issue on child route

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I have a routed in angular application called User, then i have a child route called UserDetails, when i click edit i would like to navigate to a new route (userdetails), i'm getting an error  Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/1'. Below is my routing configurations

**Excepted result**
**http://localhost:4200/user - Grid page
http://localhost:4200/user/1 - Edit page**

**app.routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './views/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: './views/user/user.module#UserModule',
      } 
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: SimpleLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: ''
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/login/login.module#LoginModule',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

**user-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'User'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user/:id',
        component: UserDetailsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'User Details'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can make changes to your user-routing.module.ts as follow.

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: UserComponent,
   data: {
     title: 'User'
   },
   children: [{
     path: 'User',
     component: UserComponent,
     pathMatch: 'full',
   },{
     path: 'user/:id',
     component: UserDetailsComponent,
     data: {
      title: 'User Details'
    }
  }
  ]
 }
```

];

> When you click on edit, call a function example

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router,
          private route: ActivatedRoute){
}
editUserData(){
  this.router.navigate([id],{relativeTo: this.route});
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @Kavitha, not working either getting same error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/1'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/1'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1765)
    at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (router.js:1730)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:131)

Answer (score 0):

In your user-routing.module.ts, try ":id" instead of "user/:id"

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'User'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: UserDetailsComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'User Details'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: no luck URL changed as excepted but UserDetailsComponent doesn't loaded. Any idea?

Comment: Does UserComponent load when you navigate to "user"?

Comment: no, i made a console log in my UserComponent constructor, it never executed

Comment: Okay. Let's get path 'user' working first. Maybe your UserModule is not loaded properly. You can inject "private route: ActivatedRoute" in your main component and see if all routes(children routes) are configured. Ex. route.children

Comment: My user module is working perfectly, issue with UserDetailsComponent

Comment: You said "UserComponent" didn't load when you navigate to "user".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167278/discussion-between-velkumar-and-brandon-chen).

Comment: @Velkumar don't forget to select the answer. Thanks.